# Page heading with php? joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 and I want to display the page heading outside of my article. Not the page title, i want the page heading. A custom page heading can be set when adding a menu item, the option is listed under the Page Display Options tab

I've got the php code to display the page title as shown below
file: /docs/templates/site/index.php

```
<h1><?$document = &JFactory::getDocument();echo $document->getTitle();?></h1>
```

Comment: Joomla 2.5? I assume you're aware that this version has been out of support since 2014 and has several known severe security issues that will not be fixed? You really should consider upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Also, please note that the "short style PHP tags" are deprecated and not supported in newer PHP versions. You should use `<?php` rather than just `<?` to start a PHP block.